# Moq'ing SharePoint for Unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio

Everything i read about unit testing mentions TypeMock isolator.  thats good when you can control what unit testing and mocking tools you are using in the project but I am unable to use TypeMock.  Instead the project uses Moq.

I cant however find a good resource for examples on Moq with sealed classes which lets face it SharePoint 2010 is full of!

Does anyone have any samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put you cannot use Moq to mock behaviour of sealed classes or at least not easily. Microsoft Research have released a free mocking framework for this purpose called Moles which is available to download from http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Let us know if this is what you're looking for and we can provide further advice and samples.

Comment: its not ideal as I cant use moles in my project but thanks :-)